# Error while Reading pub/sub message in DAG

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

On Message Published to Topic, cloud function triggers the dag.
Below is DAG I have Written to Fetch the Pub-sub Message.

```
import os
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.pubsub_sensor import PubSubPullSensor
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types import ReceivedMessage
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.utils import dates

#Specify the Project_id,Topic and Subscription.
project = 'migration'
topic = 'publish-message.' 
subscription = 'publish-message-subscription'   


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(2),
    'project': project,
    'topic': topic,
    'subscription': subscription,
}

echo_template = '''
{% for m in task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='pull-messages') %}
    echo "AckID: {{ m.get('ackId') }}, Base64-Encoded: {{ m.get('message') }}"
{% endfor %}
'''

with models.DAG(
    "example_gcp_pubsub_sensor",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,                 
    #start_date=days_ago(1),
) as example_sensor_dag:


    #subscription = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('subscribe_task') }}"
    #subscription = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('subscription') }}"

    pull_messages = PubSubPullSensor(
        task_id="pull_messages",
        ack_messages=True,
        project_id=project,
        subscription=subscription,

    )

    pull_messages_result = BashOperator(task_id="pull_messages_result", bash_command=echo_template)

    (pull_messages >> pull_messages_result)
```

I'm Geeting some error in DAG.
[image]

Task pull_message is Executed but 2nd task pull_messgaes_result is getting an error.

Comment: Looks like xcom_pull is returning None. This may be because no messages were pulled, or because the parameters to xcom_pull were not set up properly. First determine if messages came back; perhaps make a simple python-executing operator that prints the messages that are returned. Once that works, switch to using your BashOperator. Start simple and grow the code as it works.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html?highlight=xcom_pull#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.xcom_pull

Answer (score 0):

i think you can resolve your issue going  through the documentation link which i pasted below. Let me know if you don't find. I'll try another way.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-code